# Is it possible to get the invitation_id from a Github Webhook event when a user accepts an invitation?

Tags: github, github-api, github-webhook

If I send a collaboration invitation for a private Github repository via eMail, I would like to know for which Github-Profile the invitation ends up being used. Currently, an invitation sent via eMail can be used by the owner of the eMail account for any Github-Account.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no information sent in the Webhook Event to cross-reference the Acceptance-Event of an invitation by a user with the sent invitation. This denies me the ability to cross-reference emails with user-accounts for my private repository.

I was unable to find any information inside the Webhook Acceptance-Event for an invitation that would allude to the eMail address for which I created the invitation.

I assume this is due to privacy and works as intended? Or can this be accomplished?